# One AD Account logging into 50+ machines simultaneously

Tags: active-directory, authentication, domain-controller, user-accounts

I have an AD Domain set up specifically for running computer-based exams at multiple locations.  One site sits 50-100 exams and needs to start them at the exact same time and they all login to the machines with the same AD account.  Running on 2008 we had no problems doing this but on upgrading to 2016 the times to start the exam application get longer and longer the more machines try to start the exam app.  All machines are pre logged into.

Going back to the exam providers with Wireshark logs they have confirmed an unusually long authentication time between client and the DC.  We can't see any signs of issues in the event log or the infrastructure in general.

Q: So my question is could the Single AD user account be a problematic factor and would the DC have any issues processing multiple auth requests for a single user as opposed to individual accounts?  Trying to rule this out as a potential.

Comment: `could the Single AD user account be a problematic factor`. No. An authentication requires less than one second. You mention logon. There's probably a lot more than authentication during the logon in the packet capture.

Comment: Thanks Greg just what I was looking for and I'ill now not run tests with individual accounts so that's saved me a step.

Comment: Are you using roaming profiles? If so, that would be my guess as to where the logon delay is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Greg Askew gave the answer I was looking for, there should not be a difference in Authentication with single user or multiple users. "No. An authentication requires less than one second."